# Tooltip hidden behind JOGL GLCanvas on OS X when using non-Aqua look and feel

Tags: java, macos, swing, tooltip, jogl

In the following program (which depends on JOGL), the tooltip of the `JLabel` is hidden behind the heavyweight `GLCanvas` when the tooltip 'fits' inside the `GLCanvas`.

```
import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel;

import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

public class HeavyWeightTooltipTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(NimbusLookAndFeel.class.getName());
        } catch (Exception aE) {
          aE.printStackTrace();
        }
        showUI();
      }
    });
  }

  private static void showUI(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestFrame");

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Label with tooltip");
    label.setToolTipText("A very long tooltip to ensure it overlaps with the heavyweight component");
    frame.add(label, BorderLayout.WEST);

    GLCanvas glCanvas = new GLCanvas();
    frame.add(glCanvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }
}
```

**Observations**

- It only happens when not using the Aqua look and feel. I could reproduce it with Nimbus and Metal look and feels, but not with the Aqua look and feel.
- It does not happen when using a regular `java.awt.Canvas`, only with the JOGL `GLCanvas` (which is an extension of `java.awt.Canvas`)
- The tooltip is rendered correctly when the tooltip is wider than the `GLCanvas`. The problem starts as soon as the tooltip fits into the `GLCanvas` (see screenshots at the end of the post)
- It does not matter whether I call `ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false)` or not. The problem is always reproducible
- It works on Linux and Windows
- In case it is relevant, I am using JOGL version 2.3.2 and Java version 1.8.0_65

  ```
  java version "1.8.0_65"
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
  ```

**Tooltip correctly shown**
[image: Tooltip correctly shown]
**Tooltip hidden behind GLCanvas**
[image: Tooltip hidden behind GLCanvas]

Edit: I logged this in the bug tracker of JOGL as [bug 1306](https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1306).

Comment: Have you tried the tips in [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html)? Ugh.. I just noted they were saying it is 'automatic'. Try some of their code on your machine, see if **it** works.

Comment: @AndrewThompson From that article I mainly conclude that it should just work with modern JDK's. Some of the bugs mentioned in that article are already fixed, and other tips are irrelevant (like the one for the scrollpane, or the non-rectangular components).

Comment: It's a JOGL bug, please fill a bug report. Maintaining the AWT heavyweight GLCanvas is painful with OS X :s https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1277

Comment: @gouessej Funny, I bumped into that bug as well. The comment/screenshots/snippets attached yesterday were mine.

Comment: Sven started fixing this other bug, you should try his patch.

Comment: @gouessej Where can I find this patch ? Looking at the [JOGL Github repository](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/commits/master), there hasn't been any activity since November 2015

Comment: https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=786

Comment: @gouessej Thanks. I will give it a try when I am back at work next week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that forcing the `PopupFactory` to use heavyweight tooltips (instead of medium weight tooltips) fixes the issue.
This is non-trivial, and requires you to write your own `PopupFactory` or use reflection to call `PopupFactory#setPopupType`.

As I wasn't too keen on writing my own `PopupFactory`, I used reflection:

```
final class HeavyWeightTooltipEnforcerMac {

  private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
  private static PropertyChangeListener sUIManagerListener;

  private HeavyWeightTooltipEnforcerMac() {
  }

  /**
   * <p>
   *   Tooltips which overlap with the GLCanvas
   *   will be painted behind the heavyweight component when the bounds of the tooltip are contained
   *   in the bounds of the application.
   * </p>
   *
   * <p>
   *   In that case, {@code javax.swing.PopupFactory#MEDIUM_WEIGHT_POPUP} instances are used, and
   *   they suffer from this bug.
   *   Always using {@code javax.swing.PopupFactory#HEAVY_WEIGHT_POPUP} instances fixes the issue.
   * </p>
   *
   * <p>
   *   Note that the bug is only present when not using the Aqua look-and-feel.
   * Aqua uses its own {@code PopupFactory} which does not suffer from this.
   * </p>
   *
   */
  static void install() {
    synchronized (LOCK) {
      if (sUIManagerListener == null && isMacOS()) {
        installCustomPopupFactoryIfNeeded();
        sUIManagerListener = new LookAndFeelChangeListener();
        UIManager.addPropertyChangeListener(sUIManagerListener);
      }
    }
  }

  private static void installCustomPopupFactoryIfNeeded() {
    if (!isAquaLookAndFeel()) {
      PopupFactory.setSharedInstance(new AlwaysUseHeavyWeightPopupsFactory());
    }
  }

  private static final class LookAndFeelChangeListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
      String propertyName = evt.getPropertyName();
      if ("lookAndFeel".equals(propertyName)) {
        installCustomPopupFactoryIfNeeded();
      }
    }
  }

  private static class AlwaysUseHeavyWeightPopupsFactory extends PopupFactory {
    private boolean couldEnforceHeavyWeightComponents = true;

    @Override
    public Popup getPopup(Component owner, Component contents, int x, int y) throws IllegalArgumentException {
      enforceHeavyWeightComponents();
      return super.getPopup(owner, contents, x, y);
    }

    private void enforceHeavyWeightComponents() {
      if (!couldEnforceHeavyWeightComponents) {
        return;
      }
      try {
        Method setPopupTypeMethod = PopupFactory.class.getDeclaredMethod("setPopupType", int.class);
        setPopupTypeMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setPopupTypeMethod.invoke(this, 2);
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException aE) {
        //If it fails once, it will fail every time. Do not try again
        //Consequence is that tooltips which overlap with a heavyweight component will be painted behind that component iso
        //on top of it
        couldEnforceHeavyWeightComponents = false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

A similar fix can be found in the IntelliJ community edition: the [`LafManagerImpl`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/0d07f8486ce48fd75cf7df9da38c917dd2bb8ffa/platform/platform-impl/src/com/intellij/ide/ui/laf/LafManagerImpl.java) class sets its own factory in the `fixPopupWeight` method, which enforces heavyweight popups.

Comment: Interesting, could you write a page about it on the wiki?

Comment: Have you ever filled a bug report as suggested? StackOverflow isn't a bug tracker as far as I know. Thank you for sharing your findings anyway.

Comment: @gouessej It is indeed not a bug tracker, but people here might know a workaround. If Sven is indeed back to fixing issues, I will file a few bug reports (as I bumped into a few other ones)

Comment: @gouessej Bug report is now available at https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1306